# Decode back Javascript base64 unicode with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

I have this encode function in Javascript:

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}
```

How to decode it under PHP ?

**I tried:**

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(base64_decode($str));
```

But i got a depreciated characters like:

```
�]��\��H���
```

Can you suggest a solution please ?

**Example of encoded html code:**

```
<div class="pattern">
  <div class="gbody"></div>
  <div class="eyes">
    <div class="eye left"></div>
    <div class="eye right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mouth"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="gshadow"></div>
</div>
```

The javascript return:

```
CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ2JvZHkiPjwvZGl2PgogIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImV5ZXMiPgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIGxlZnQiPjwvZGl2PgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIHJpZ2h0Ij48L2Rpdj4KICA8L2Rpdj4KICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJtb3V0aCI PC9kaXY CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0id2F2ZSI PC9kaXY CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ3NoYWRvdyI PC9kaXY CjwvZGl2Pg==
```

**Here the decode function in Javascript:**

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

**EDIT:**

`str` with chinese characters:

`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`

**NB:** The Javascript encode function is required in my project.

Comment: an example of `$str` would be nice

Comment: A long html code ... you can try any texts for testing.

Comment: I put an example of encoded string with Javascript.

Comment: Do you see those spaces in the base64-encoded string?

Comment: I edited my question with a javascript decode function ...

Comment: @Federkun yes i see them, please check the decode function in javascript to understand how to decode it in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base64_decode` is enough. Your problem is (probably) how you send your js-base64encoded string to php.

`b64EncodeUnicode` **can't** return this:

> CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ2JvZHkiPjwvZGl2PgogIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImV5ZXMiPgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIGxlZnQiPjwvZGl2PgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIHJpZ2h0Ij48L2Rpdj4KICA8L2Rpdj4KICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJtb3V0aCI
>   PC9kaXY CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0id2F2ZSI PC9kaXY
>   CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ3NoYWRvdyI PC9kaXY CjwvZGl2Pg==

Do you see the spaces? `b64EncodeUnicode` probably returned this instead:

> CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ2JvZHkiPjwvZGl2PgogIDxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImV5ZXMiPgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIGxlZnQiPjwvZGl2PgogICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZXllIHJpZ2h0Ij48L2Rpdj4KICA8L2Rpdj4KICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJtb3V0aCI+PC9kaXY+CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0id2F2ZSI+PC9kaXY+CiAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iZ3NoYWRvdyI+PC9kaXY+CjwvZGl2Pg==

What you need to do to solve your problem? For instance, if you pass it inside the querystring of the php page, you should url-encode it. You can use `encodeURIComponent` to do it.

Comment: I want to decode it from PHP, and please see the decode function in JAVASCRIPT ... it's not a standard decode function.

Comment: No it important, since the btoa function do not support special characters like chinese characters ect...

Comment: Already tried it but with no good result, i have only this solution to do it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: An HTML code with chinese characters, russian, indien too do not work.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Bh5SZ - did you read the contents with the utf-8 encoding? (put a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on top)

Comment: But it's not a correct solution ... since the b64EncodeUnicode(str) function replace and add some characters that must be reversed in the decode function.

Comment: It doesn't replace or add any additional characters. You can try yourself: `b64EncodeUnicode("chinese_string_here");` returns the same value as `base64_encode("chinese_string_here")`. **base64_decode is enough.**

Comment: base64_encode is enough in PHP, encoding must be from javascript side, and decoding from PHP.

Comment: are you able to find a value returned from `b64EncodeUnicode` that  `base64_decode` can't decode correctly?

Comment: @Federkun everything works, you can read my updated answer. I believe the problem is that the asker just has a console different than UTF-8 and thus echo base64_decode($str) doesn't work for him as he expects it.

Comment: I accept your answer, but that didn't solved my problem totally ... anyway many thank's for your help.

Comment: I can help you until it does. How this didn't work well to you?

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me:

```
function decodeSpacedB64($b64) {
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $b64)));
}

echo decodeSpacedB64(/* ...your_string... */);
```

As you might have noticed that you have spaces in your string, and thus, you should replace them with pluses if you want the standard php `base64_decode()` function to be able to decode your string.

**UPDATE**

The asker claims that Russian and Chinese are not possible to decode with `base64_decode()`. This is totally not true:

*STEP 1* (JS)

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

var str = b64EncodeUnicode("проверка связи");
console.log(str); // outputs "0L/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsCDRgdCy0Y/Qt9C4"
```

*STEP 2* (PHP)

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(base64_decode("0L/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsCDRgdCy0Y/Qt9C4"));
// outputs "проверка связи"
```

Probably, the asker had a problem with the console encoding in his system (indeed, having an encoding different than UTF-8 will lead to garbage instead of text).

Comment: OP's problem is that he corrupt the string when he pass it to php. This fix the symptoms but not the problem.

Comment: Please take a look to javascript decode function to see the process, i need to ocnvert it to PHP.

Comment: @Federkun, you are right, and the OP seems not to understand it. But I believe, there could be the cases, when you have no choice but to use a workaround (like purely designed frontend that is not under your control). But in general, yes, the best solution is to solve a problem rather than the consequence.

Comment: standard base64 decode/encode do not work in chinese, russian and indien characters ... my question is based on this. to convert the javascript function to php.

Comment: It does work, I just checked: `echo htmlspecialchars_decode(base64_decode("0L/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsCDRgdCy0Y/Qt9C4"));` it outputs Russian `проверка связи`. (the Base64 encoded string is received from `b64EncodeUnicode`).